# jQuery custom scroll causes flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, flicker, custom-scrolling

I'm using this [jQuery custom content scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and it causes the scrollable section to flicker.

- On clicking another random button it continuously flickers
- If I take no action, it flickers on every few seconds interval

The code used:

```
$('.custom-scrollbar').mCustomScrollbar({
  scrollInertia: 0,
  alwaysShowScrollbar: 1, // adding / removing this causes no difference
  scrollbarPosition: 'outside'
});
```

Attached a gif to demonstrate the issue: http://gyazo.com/9ea9d558f2630c74a157c70a367d1868

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it helps anyone: As a fix, I just added a 1px padding for the container; no more flickering.

Answer (score 0):

This custom scrollbar flicks when its container has padding. Remove any padding from this container in css. Fox ex.

```
.mCSB_container.mCS_no_scrollbar_y.mCS_y_hidden
{
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a CSS solution that worked in my specific case but disabling the [`updateOnContentResize` advanced setting](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#plugin-data-advanced-updateOnContentResize) did the trick (of course, at the price of disabling the corresponding feature):

```
$(".content").mCustomScrollbar({
    advanced: {
        updateOnContentResize: false
    }
});
```